# Click event when on resize not triggered

Tags: jquery

I'm having some difficulties with a certain click event, on window resize.

Here's the run-down:

- when the screen is smaller than a value, a li item that has child ul elements will receive a class, and a click on that li item will add a class to itself;
- the same condition will be applied on init, just to check if we're in that screen value

The issue:

- On init, when the condition is not met, the click isn't supposed to do anything; however on resize, when that condition will be met, its supposed to run, which is my issue with it: it doesn't run on resize when the condition is met
- Vice-versa: when the condition is met, the the resize takes place, and the condition will no longer be met, the click shouldn't work;

I've made a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vuypu/1/) to illustrate my issue; just shrink up/down the results window to check the condition

Any ideas or suggestions are more than welcomed,
Thanks!

The mark-up:

```
<nav class='navigation-wrap'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href='#'>Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='#'>Link with childs</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href='#'>Link</a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href='#'>Link</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The js:

```
if ( $(window).width()<800 ){
    $('.navigation-wrap li:has(ul)').addClass('mobile-nav');
        }else{
    $('.navigation-wrap li:has(ul)').removeClass('mobile-nav');
};

$( window ).resize(function() {
    if ( $(window).width()<800 ){
        $('.navigation-wrap li:has(ul)').addClass('mobile-nav');
    }else{
        $('.navigation-wrap li:has(ul)').removeClass('mobile-nav');
    };
 });

$('li.mobile-nav > a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('mobile-nav-is-triggered');
    return false;
});
```

The css:

```
.mobile-nav{
    background: red;
}
.mobile-nav-is-triggered{
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: Might be a misunderstanding - but why do you say that 'On init, when the condition is not met'? Can't I open the page inside a small window? Should this realy depend on the resize event or on the size of the window?

Comment: Well when the page is loaded and that condition is met, the click takes place, otherwise is shouldn't do anything. It goes the same for when you resize the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are adding class `mobile-nav` dynamically, You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached.

*Code*

```
$('.navigation-wrap').on('click', 'li.mobile-nav > a', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('mobile-nav-is-triggered');
    return false;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/PmA7A/)

Comment: Yep this is what I was looking for. Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).on('click','li.mobile-nav > a',function(e) {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('mobile-nav-is-triggered');
  return false;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vuypu/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I have to ask - is the purpose of adding the classes simply to style the nav differently or are your examples with changing the colors simply for demonstration? Because the example provided could be done with css quite simply using a media query.

In you need them for targeting some new behavior in javascript when the screen is small, then as the others have said, using event delegation will solve it.

Comment: Im a js newbie :) yes it can be done with mq, but that's just an example, in the real picture, things happen different but, that was my issue with it: the darn event delegation; reading about it atm :)